# Changing popup to different html file upon user sign-in: Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am building a Chrome Extension (with Manifest V3) and I want the default popup (signup-popup.html) to be a sign up page for users (providing their "username" only). After users submit their name, I want the popup window to dynamically change to the default account popup (account-popup.html) which will display if users are signed in according to a boolean variable in chrome.storage.local. Once users are signed in, the default popup will be account-popup.html. How do I go about achieving this?

This is what I have so far in my signup-popup.js. So far this seems to work when I close and re-open the extensions popup by clicking on the icon. However, I would like the popup window to dynamically change on submit.

```
    chrome.storage.local.get("username", function (data) {
        if (data.username) {
            console.log(data.username);
            chrome.action.setPopup({ popup: "default-popup.html" }, function () {
                console.log('popup set to default-popup');
            });
        } else {
            console.log('no username');
            chrome.action.setPopup({ popup: "signup-popup.html" });
        }
    });
```

This is my first Chrome extension project so I appreciate any advice and recommendations.

Comment: You also need `location.href = 'newpopup.html'`

Comment: @wOxxOm
Thank you! I am definitely learning a lot with this project